# Provisioning timeout on ubuntu VM

Tags: azure, iaas

I tried to create a Ubuntu server VM with the new feature, but my VM is in state : Running (Provisioning Timed Out) and I can't connect to it (authentication error)

Any clue please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The best way to address this question is to go to dedicated Windows Azure Virtual Machine for Linux forums below:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforLinux/threads

Please provide your exact authentication error and based on that info, someone will work with you to resolve your problem.